# Ruby list an objects instance methods without it's getters and/or setters

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'd like to be able to list all of an objects classes instance methods without getters and setters from `attr_accessor`. I've written this as an example and it behaves the way I need it to.

I find it hard to believe that there isn't an easier way to do this.

```
class Object
  def instance_methods_without_variables
    self.class.instance_methods(false).reject {|x| x.to_s.include? "=" } -
      self.instance_variables.map {|x| x.to_s[1..-1].to_sym }
  end
end

class TestClass
  attr_accessor :var1, :var2

  def initialize
    @var1 = 'var1'
    @var2 = 'var2'
  end

  def method1() 'method1' end
  def method2() 'method2' end
end

t = TestClass.new
p t.instance_methods_without_variables
# => [:method1, :method2]
```

EDIT:

After reviewing the answers I've opted to use the following method *within my class*, not Object.

```
def instance_methods_without_variables
  self.class.instance_methods(false).reject { |method|
    self.instance_variables.any? { |variable| method.to_s.include? variable.to_s[1..-1] } ||
    method == __method__
  }
end
```

This also works with `attr_reader` & `attr_writer`

Comment: "without variables"?  You've only selected those methods who have no complimentary setter.  If you did `def method1=() nil end` you would lose `:method1` from your list

Comment: I've updated the title to getters and setters instead of instance variables.

The functionality here is as I'd like it - I'm only asking if there's a way to get this same result without using such a hacky method.

Comment: Why do you find this "hard to believe"? Why would you need this functionality and since you do why would you not expect it to be a hack? When I want a list of `methods` I would like it to be complete when I don't want a complete list I expect to have to modify it. e.g. (in irb I use `some_object.methods.sort - Object.methods` all the time)

Comment: Getters and setters are just methods. Of course they're returned by `.methods`. Why do you find this "hard to believe"?

Comment: I just found it surprising that there wasn't an easier way to exclude getter and setters from the methods list. I was looking for a neater way to achieve this, rather than modifying methods list every time.

Comment: I have wanted to do this myself, actually.  I just wanted to see if you were going at it for any other reason.

Comment: It is one of the *fundamental* principles of object-oriented programming that you *cannot* know whether a particular feature is implemented with data or with an operation. It is therefore *impossible* to distinguish between a method which returns pre-computed data (a getter) or a method which computes its result on-the-fly. Note that your methods `method1` and `method2` above return pre-computed data and are thus getters, yet you want them included in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ruby language has no notion of getters and setters for properties.  `attr_accessor :a_var` is merely a convenient shorthand for creating the methods `:a_var` that returns the value, and `:a_var=` that set the value of the instance variable `@a_var`.  The methods `:a_var`, and `:a_var=` are no different than any other method defined in the containing class.

So you have a need for a partial list of instance methods, that excludes those ending in `=`, and those that have an instance variable of the same name.

I think you have a reasonable method for implementing that behavior, though I don't think this should be implemented on `Object`.

Comment: I've opted to include a method for this in my class based on your recommendation. I've adjusted it to work on attr_reader and attr_writers too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do this lots, probably better that you <strike>overwrite `attr_accessor`</strike> write your own `custom_attr_accessor`

```
class AuditedClass

    def indexed_attr_accessor(*args)
        self.class_eval %Q{
          unless instance_variable_get(:@attr_accessor_index).is_a?(Array)
            instance_variable_set :@attr_accessor_index = []
          end

          # getter for easy access to attr_accessor list
          def attr_accessor_index
            @attr_accessor_index
          end

          def non_attr_instance_methods
            self.class.instance_methods(false).reject {|x| x.to_s.include? "=" } - @attr_accessor_index
          end

        }

        # iterate through each passed in argument...
        args.each do |arg|

            # getter
            self.class_eval("def #{arg};@#{arg};end")

            # setter
            self.class_eval("def #{arg}=(val);@#{arg}=val;end")

            # updated index
            self.class_eval("@attr_accessor_index << :#{arg}")
        end

    end

end

class TestClass < AuditedClass
  indexed attr_accessor :var1, :var2

  def initialize
    @var1 = 'var1'
    @var2 = 'var2'
  end

  def method1() 'method1' end
  def method2() 'method2' end
end

t = TestClass.new
p t.attr_accessor_index
#=> [:var1, :var2]

p t.non_attr_instance_methods
#=> [:method1, :method2]
```

If you won't do this often, then best not to load up on memory usage with every object instantiation.  Instead, just use your proposed method.

Comment: Wow, okay - this looks cool! However I'm having trouble seeing how I can use this to achieve the behaviour above.

Comment: Yea, right, sorry - I'm running out of time here and though just of the index, rather than the inverse that you're looking to have.  I just added what you need, but pardon that I didn't test this; I have to go.  Hope it sets up your solution

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a quick hack that relies on the fact that when you do Class.instance_variables(false), Ruby first displays the accessors/mutators methods in pairs of 2, and then the regular methods show up (this will work only if you don't put any methods above attr_accessor in your class definition). It's not perfect, but it's the shortest code I could come up with:

```
methods_without_accessors = A.instance_methods(false).each_slice(2).reject do |x|
  x[0].to_s.gsub('=', '') == x[1].to_s.gsub('=', '')
end.flatten
```

each_slice(2) will group the getter/setters (see the text above for cases where that might not work) and with reject you're excluding them with a simple rule. Flatten makes sure you get a single array, not a double one with the groups for which the .reject evaluated to false.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've opted for a slightly more robust approach that handles attr_reader and attr_writers too - see note on question.